# What is the best architecture to run Oracle sucessfully run on VMWare?

Tags: oracle, architecture

Due to a data center move we are mandated to migrate all servers to virtual machines. We currently have a 3 Node Oracle RAC running on physical servers. There seems to be a great debate about the suitability of running Oracle on virtual machines especially as RAC would not be part of the new system. What is the best architecture to run Oracle successfully run on VMWare?

Comment: Do you have Oracle Support? What version of Oracle are you running and do you need the platform to be [certified](http://blogs.oracle.com/UPGRADE/entry/is_oracle_certified_to_run_on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Oracle under VMware just fine.  The big question is what is the current hardware spec and what VMware version and edition will be hosting the database?